# Linker error comes while running as well as testing the Xcode workspace after updating KIF framework via cocoapods

Tags: ios7, xcode5, cocoapods, kif-framework, kif

I have an Xcode workspace in which I have updated to KIF 2.0(pod update via terminal & pod 'KIF' in the podfile) after that I have configured the workspace as per the instructions provided in https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF#configure-the-testing-target(installation with Cocoapods section).But when I tried to execute the project as well as Run my test target it throws an error,

```
ld: building for iOS Simulator, but linking against dylib built for MacOSX file '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/SenTestingKit.framework/SenTestingKit' for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have also checked this link:https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/kif-framework/EilvCp2psZA/huUQ3sGpmwQJ . But still the issue persists.

How can I correct it? The screen shot is provided below.[image]

When I tried to Run it using iPhone 5 it shows 5 linker error such as

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/SenTestingKit.framework/SenTestingKit, missing required architecture armv7s in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/SenTestingKit.framework/SenTestingKit (2 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_SenTestCase", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_KIFTestCase in libPods.a(KIFTestCase.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SenTestCase", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_KIFTestCase in libPods.a(KIFTestCase.o)
      l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_SenTestCase_$_KIFAdditions in libPods.a(SenTestCase-KIFAdditions.o)
  "_SenTestToolKey", referenced from:
      +[KIFTestActor load] in libPods.a(KIFTestActor.o)
  "_SenSelfTestMain", referenced from:
      +[KIFTestActor load] in libPods.a(KIFTestActor.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Same issue here with the latest cocoa pods version.

You can solve this by following this steps:

- Select the Pods project
- Click on build settings
- Change Build Active Architecture Only to 'No'

Comment: I have done the same thing you mentioned.But it still shows the same isssues.I have restarted the Xcode 5 and tried to Run it again.But the issue persists.:(

Comment: In my projects for all targets, build_activ_arch_only debug section is set as Yes.

Comment: Strange, are you sure you set the key of the Pods project and not your Nexercise_iPhone project?

Comment: Yes.I have set the Nexercise_iPhone project build_active_arch_only as No and pods project as Yes.

Comment: You should change the Build Active Architecture Only from the Pods project to 'No' instead of 'Yes'

Comment: I did the same but still error persists..I am trying to resolve this for the past 2 days...

Comment: Sorry, out of inspiration, this workaround did the trick for me.

Comment: I have posted the issue on github : https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF/issues/288 but no reply has came upto yet.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40563/discussion-between-user1884775-and-nsmutablestring)

Comment: This works for me.  After I set Build Active Architecture Only to 'NO' for pod project, the errors are gone.

Comment: i had to work hours to get it working ... but finally setting Build Active Architecture Only to YES worked for me !!!

Answer (score 2):

Go to your target settings and add SenTestingKit to Link binary with libraries.

Comment: Adding the SenTestingKit framework to the libraries does not make any difference.. :(

Comment: Alright, so then go to Configurations under Info Tab on your project Target, disclose Debug config and then select the KIF Bundle Test Target and point it to right KIF pod configuration file. It should something like, `Pods-<TestTarget>Pods.config`.

Comment: In the Info Tab on my project Target,under custom iOS target properties I can see a configuration key and it is set as ${CONFIGURATION}. Is that the one you specified?

Comment: I added a 'libPods-MyProjectTests-KIF.a' to `Link Binary With Libraries` on my test target, and it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me to remove the XCTest framework. I know that might be something you don't want to do though.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem with the help of my colleague.
Two steps:
1、just update the cocoapods to 0.29.0,because 0.29.0 just fix a bug,more detail ,see:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1558
use command:
sudo gem  install cocoapods
pod install 
pod update
2、if you want run your app on ios devices,just change the Build Settings->Architectures,the value of it to (Standard Architecture (armv7,armv7s)),